# Multiply: $(4 + x)(x^2 + 2x +3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I solve this:
Multiply:  $(4 + x)(x^2 + 2x +3)$

Comment: How would you multiply $(a+b) \cdot c$  ?

Comment: Distribute. Multiply. Add.

Answer (score 5):

This question, as you probably know, requires the use of the distributive property. To use JavaMan's suggestion $$(a + b) \cdot c = a \cdot c + b \cdot c$$ 
Let "a + b" be your $4 + x$ and let "c" be your $x^2 + 2x + 3$ 
Then we need to multiply $a \cdot c$, or $4 \cdot (x^2 + 2x + 3)$, and add it to 
$b \cdot c$, which is $x \cdot (x^2 + 2x + 3)$ 
So $$ a\cdot c + b \cdot c = [4\cdot (x^2 + 2x +3)] + [x \cdot (x^2 + 2x + 3)]$$
After taking these steps, combine like terms and write the result in order of decreasing exponents (for convention's sake)

Answer (score 2):

First, distribute the 4. Add the products of 4 and $x^2$, 4 and 2x, 3 and 4.

Then, distribute the x. Add the products of x and $x^2$, x and 2x, 3 and x.

Then all you have to do is add all of the items you have left.

After the distributions, you should have

$4x^2 + 8x + 12 + x^3 + x^2 + 3x =$

$x^3 + 5x^2  +11x + 12$

(Yay cool text!)

Comment: just put dollar signs around the parts you want to cool-ify.